# How to download GeoTIFFs using the REST API in GeoServer 2.2?

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, rest, api, download

I am using GeoServer (Version 2.2 Git Revision f5b5c35076b52d02eb9cca3fa3232bc17b5f6d80 Build Date 19-Sep-2012 18:33 GeoTools Version 8.2 (rev 704570474295e339c08d1ca140d884f23a8a03a3)) and I have a workspace named `myTestWorkspace` and stored with name `test` and type `GeoTIFF`.

This store has URL connection parameters as follows: `file:coverages/test.tif`. I would like to download `*.tif` file by GeoServer REST API.

I found in [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/restconfig/rest-config-api.html#coverage-stores) that it is possible using URL

`/workspaces/<ws>/coveragestores/<cs>/file[.<extension>]`

So in my case it will be `/workspaces/myTestWorkspace/coveragestores/test/file.geotiff` (am I right?). But when I paste this URL I've got `HTTP status 404`. In documentation above is information that in this case (getting 404) are two options:

> Exceptions:
>
> GET for a data store that does not exist -> 404 
> GET for a data store
>   that is not file based -> 404

My data store exists (if for example I paste `/workspaces/myTestWorkspace/coveragestores/test/file.tif` then I've got `Unsupported format: tif` in response - this is ok, because `tif` is not valid format, so it means that GeoServer can see my store).

But is my data store file based? I thought that if data store has type `GeoTIFF`, then he is file based - am I right?
Any ideas why I cannot download TIFF file?

Thanks

Comment: what do you see if you ask for /workspaces/myTestWorkspace/coveragestores/test/ ? I think you should see a list of files that are available

Comment: I see:  'Coverage Store "test"

    test' (second 'test' is hyperlink to /workspaces/gsip/coveragestores/test/coveragestores/test.html) but when I paste /workspaces/myTestWorkspace/coveragestores/test.xml then I get normal information about store (name, description, type, enabled etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Try using &format=image/tiff

This is the format that works for me when getting tiffs from Geoserver's web coverage service:

http://myserver/geoserver/myworkspace/wcs?service=WCS&version=2.0.1&request=GetCoverage&CoverageId=myworkspace:mycoverage&format=image/tiff

Comment: when I use WCS service for download GeoTIFF with large size (about 7Gb) I receive exception: "The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/imagespace/wcs?
Read Timeout
The system returned: [No Error]
A Timeout occurred while waiting to read data from the network. The network or server may be down or congested. Please retry your request." Is it possible to increase the value of "Timeout" for download files with large size? Thanks!